# HTML with JS to Image/PDF

Tags: java, javascript, html

Is it possible to convert an html page with charts generated by javascript to an Image or PDF in Java?

I familiar with iText framework and it seems to be suitable but I am not sure how it handle JS generated things.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turned up [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/java-jsp-35/how-print-html-file-java-379867.html#post2739573) as a possible answer.
Using a library to convert to XSL-FO then another one to convert that to PDF.

Edit: [This](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/forDevelopers/sdk12print.html) might interest you as well. There's a bit on some JBrowser class that seems to let you print web pages.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the were generated. I suppose three possibilities:

1. Canvas tag.
   You need to add a bit of JS code to get image using `toDataURL` canvas method
2. SVG.
   You can add some code to get the full code of generated SVG document via innerHTML method.
3. Flash.
   The worst case. I think it's hardly possible to achive what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** 
If you have access to plain HTML (taken after the JavaScript has executed and built the page), you can easily pass it to iText and convert it to PDF. I would recommend using Flyng-Saucer (which in turn uses iText) which has a very good and convenient API for this (See http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ ).

**Solution 2**  
On the other hand, if you do not have access to the final HTML output, you could use the Swing libraries to render the page and then take a screenshot of it. This will allow you to even use Flash, but I'm not sure whether this approach will be suitable to your problem.

However, if it is the case, you can load the web page into a Swing application (you will need to rely on a third-party browser component for JS support, but there are quite a lot out there), and then you can use the Robot class to get a screenshot of it.

Take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html